# regex: matching complement of a group

Tags: regex, latex

Using `regex` I am tryign to do the following:

Given a string `(a,b'x',{de}'y',f)` I want to get `(,x,y,)`. Meaning I want to keep only the things between `' '` and the symbols `,` , `(` and `)`. I can delete things between `' '` by using `('.*?')` and I thought `[^('.*?')]` will serve the purpose, but it doesn't work.

I also tried `^(?!.*('.*?'))` for deleting everything but `'...'`,  this too doesn't work.

I am using this code in `LaTeX` and characters may be Unicode characters. Please help me in extracting this.

Comment: Does Latex support lookarrounds? If so try matching with `[(),]|(?<=')[a-z](?=')`, where `(?<=')` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?<=')` is a *positive lookahead*.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thanks for your comment. Sadly Latex doesn't support look around yet. Also, your code matches the complement of what I want.

Comment: x-post: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1105